# Custom log4j.properties on AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, emr

I am unable to override and use a Custom log4j.properties on Amazon EMR. I am running Spark on EMR (Yarn) and have tried all the below combinations in the Spark-Submit to try and use the custom log4j.

```
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=hdfs://host:port/user/hadoop/log4j.properties"

--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=hdfs://host:port/user/hadoop/log4j.properties"
```

I have also tried picking from local filesystem using file://// instead of hdfs. None of this seem to work. However, I can get this working when running on my local Yarn setup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Basically, after chatting with the support and reading the documentation, I see that there are 2 options available to do this:

1 - Pass the `log4j.properties` through configuration passed when bringing up EMR. Jonathan has mentioned this on his answer.

2 - Include the `--files /path/to/log4j.properties` switch to your `spark-submit` command. This will distribute the `log4j.properties` file to the working directory of each Spark Executor, then change your `-Dlog4jconfiguration` to point to the filename only: `"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"`

Comment: The solution 2 is also works if the Spark job running in the cluster? like i have 20-40machines, each worker also can read the log4j properties file? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

log4j knows nothing about HDFS, so it can't accept an hdfs:// path as its configuration file. See [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for more information about configuring log4j in general.

To configure log4j on EMR, you may use the [Configuration API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html) to add key-value pairs to the log4j.properties file that is loaded by the driver and executors. Specifically, you want to add your Properties to the spark-log4j configuration classification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution which worked quite well in my case

1. ssh to the EMR cluster via terminal
2. Go to the conf directory (***cd /usr/lib/spark/conf***)
3. Replace the **log4j.properties** file with your custom values.
4. Make sure you are editing the file with root user access(type sudo -i to login as a root user)

**Note**: All the spark applications running in this cluster will output the logs defined in the custom log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

For those using terraform, it can be cumbersome to define a bootstrap action to create a new log4j file within in EMR or update the default one `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties`, because this will recreate the EMR cluster.

In this case, it's possible to use s3 paths in `--files` option so something like `--files=s3://my-bucket/log4j.properties` is valid. As mentioned by @Kaptrain, EMR will distribute the log4j.properties file to the working directory of each Spark Executor. Then we can pass these two flags to our Spark jobs in order to use the new log4j configuration:

- spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
- spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties